# Unity3D - How to detect whether a character has landed after a jump

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

In my `Update()` function I have:

```
isGrounded = Physics2D.Linecast (transform.position, groundCheck.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ground"));

if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump") && isGrounded) {
    jump = true;
}
```

I make my character jump using this code in `FixedUpdate()`:

```
if (jump) {
    anim.SetTrigger("Jump");
    rb.AddForce(new Vector2 (0f, jumpForce));
    jump = false;
}
```

I have to detect the moment at which my character lands on the ground (`isGrounded` will then become true) to switch the animation back to Idle. I can't use `isGrounded` to detect it because as you can see the jump is performed when `isGrounded` is true, so the Idle animation trigger would launch at the same time as the jump animation giving either little or no jump animation at all.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by dividing the jumping animation into jumping that transitions into falling. Animation switches to those states based on whether the y axis movement is positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have a floor gameobject with which jumping character collides when fall? so using `OnCollisionEnter` should work.

Comment: Does this check launch even when my character is standing on the ground before jumping? If yes then it won't work.

Comment: ok, can you manage these states using enum? steaystate,walkingstate,jumpingstate etc? if jumping and collision occurs the desired condition meets?

Comment: I actually solved this dividing the jumping animation into jumping, and then falling. Animation switches to those states based on the y axis velocity. Thank you though for your help.